# Do we need to scale our features before applying ICA, like in PCA?

Tags: pca, feature-scaling, independent-component-analysis

I am reasonably certain that we don't need to scale data before applying ICA, like we do for the PCA. In PCA we do this because it assumes normal distribution of the features, and in ICA we don't impose such a requirement. Is that a correct line of thought?

Comment: You do not need to scale data before doing PCA. And PCA does not assume the variables are normally distributed. And, in any case, scaling a variable wont' make it normally distributed.     PCA does use correlations, and these can be affected by non-normality. But that effect may be what you want. And scaling does affect PCA, but you may want to use unscaled or scaled variables, depending on the situation.

Comment: `fastICA` does whitening as a step in computing the ICA. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/97704/does-ica-require-to-run-pca-first Many additional relevant threads with the [tag:independent-component-analysis] tag can be found using a search.

Comment: as @peter-flom said PCA does not require an assumption of normal distribution (PCA is not a statistical method, it is a data reduction method), but some popular statistical metrics commonly used post-PCA do require normality. With ICA it is regularly stated that at most one underlying factor should be normally distributed. Separation of latent factors in ICA is based on kurtosis and it is not possible to separate out kurtosis of two normal distributions. The pre-processing for both methods is mostly about getting comparable variation in the underlying factors for interpretable output.